# Matplotlib / Seaborn Countplot with different Categories in one Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two series with different lengths and amount of variables and want to plot how often each variable (Name) occurs per series.
I want a grey countplot for series 1 and a red countplot for series 2, and I want them to be shown on top of each other.
However, since series 2 is missing 'Nancy' it is also cutting series 1 count of 'Nancy'. 
How do i get a full overlay of the two series inkluding a bar for Nancy?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

ser1 = pd.Series( ['tom','tom','bob','bob','nancy'])
ser2 = pd.Series( ['tom','bob'])

fig = plt.figure()
sns.countplot(x=ser1, color='grey')
sns.countplot(x=ser2, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit:
Changing to the following will cause problems again. How do I make Matplotlib recognize that the two series have the same categorical values that are being counted?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

ser1 = pd.Series( ['tom','tom','bob','bob','nancy','zulu'])
ser2 = pd.Series( ['tom','nancy'])

ser1 = ser1.astype('category')
ser2 = ser2.astype('category')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = sns.countplot(x=ser2, color='red', zorder=2)
sns.countplot(x=ser1, color='grey')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may store the setting for the first plot and restore them after having plotted the second plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

ser1 = pd.Series( ['tom','tom','bob','bob','nancy','zulu'])
ser2 = pd.Series( ['tom','bob'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = sns.countplot(x=ser1, color='grey')
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ticklabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
lim = ax.get_xlim()

sns.countplot(x=ser2, color='red')
ax.set_xlim(lim)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The other option could be to plot the second plot first but set the zorder to a higher value, such that those bars appear in front of the later plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

ser1 = pd.Series( ['tom','tom','bob','bob','nancy','zulu'])
ser2 = pd.Series( ['tom','bob'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = sns.countplot(x=ser2, color='red', zorder=2)
sns.countplot(x=ser1, color='grey')

plt.show()
```

In the more general case you need to use the `order` arument.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

ser1 = pd.Series( ['tom','tom','bob','bob','nancy', 'nancy' ,'zulu'])
ser2 = pd.Series( ['tom','nancy'])
order = ser1.append(ser2).unique()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = sns.countplot(x=ser2, color='red', order=order, zorder=2)
sns.countplot(x=ser1, color='grey', order=order)

plt.show()
```

---

In case you would rather use matplotlib's categoricals to create the plot, this would look as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ser1 = pd.Series( ['tom','tom','bob','bob','nancy', 'nancy' ,'zulu'])
ser2 = pd.Series( ['tom','nancy'])

u1, counts1 = np.unique(ser1.values, return_counts=True)
u2, counts2 = np.unique(ser2.values, return_counts=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(u1,counts1, color='grey')
ax.bar(u2,counts2, color='red')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast solution! I'm using the zorder trick now.

Comment: Unfortunatley, matplotlib does not recognize the categories. If i change my series to: ser1 = pd.Series( ['tom','tom','bob','bob','nancy','zulu'])
ser2 = pd.Series( ['tom','nancy']) The results will be incorrect. Even when the series dtype('category')

Comment: I updated the answer with zulu, it works as expected.

Comment: If you change ser2 to ser2 = pd.Series( ['tom','nancy']) the categories won't match anymore.

Comment: I updated the answer. Note that you are using seaborn countplot here, so this does not use matplotlib categorical axes but numerical axes that seaborn creates internally. I also added a solution with matplotlib for comparisson.